# Can one have more than one OAUTH2 servers in quarkus?

Tags: quarkus, elytron

One can define an OAUTH2 server easily based on the [quarkus documentation](https://quarkus.io/guides/security-oauth2).

```
quarkus.oauth2.client-id=XXXX
quarkus.oauth2.client-secret=YYYY
quarkus.oauth2.introspection-url=https://example.com/oauth2/...
```

How should I configure quarkus if I have to give the option to the users to choose their own OAUTH2 provider (github, gitlab, whatever)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution can be running separate Quarkus instances for each OAuth2 provider.

If you need to have all requests to be sent to same path and port, a mediator instance can be created for handling requests and sending them to appropriate instance with chosen OAuth2 provider.

Comment: Thank you for that idea, that could indeed solve the problem.